# Time Picker to Property Not Saved to SQLite DB

Tags: codenameone

I have a property like this:

```
public final IntProperty<SignInList> meetingTime = new IntProperty<>("meetingTime");
```

Which is bound to a picker like this:

```
PickerComponent meetingTime = PickerComponent.createTime(signInList.meetingTime.getInt()).label("Meeting time");
uib.bind(signInList.meetingTime, meetingTime.getPicker());
c.add(layout.createConstraint().widthPercentage(50), meetingTime);
```

I attempt to save the Property to a database table like this:

```
Database db = Display.getInstance().openOrCreate(DATABASE_NAME);
SQLMap sqlMap = SQLMap.create(db);
sqlMap.setPrimaryKeyAutoIncrement(signInList, signInList.id);
sqlMap.insert(signInList);
```

In the simulator using Intellij IDEA on Windows 10 this works perfectly.  On an actual Android device the time value is NOT saved.  It is saved as zero.  At the time the save button is clicked I pop up a dialog like this:

```
Dialog.show("Meeting Time", "Meeting time=" + signInList.meetingTime.getInt(), "OK", null);
```

And that shows the correct minute value (e.g. 480 for 8:00).  However, I show the same dialog when the records are then read from the database right after saving and the value is 0. What am I doing wrong?  Again, this ONLY occurs on the device.  All of the other property values from components including a different date picker get saved correctly.  It's just this time value that is getting wiped.

Is there a step that needs to take place to ensure that values from components have actually been picked up by the property?  I am doing the database writes and the refresh of the list of values (where the data is read from the DB again) in a callSerially() but I did that AFTER discovering this bug thinking it would fix it.  It did not.

If my explanation is lacking I suppose I can write a full sample application that proves it but I'm hoping this is a known issue or a common mistake that I'm making.  What am I doing wrong?  Where else can I look to troubleshoot this?

**EDIT**: This is unrelated to the picker.  I created a simpler example that demonstrates this problem.  Output in the simulator works and output on a device is broken.

The form:

```
package com.tvc.sisa;

import com.codename1.db.Database;
import com.codename1.io.Log;
import com.codename1.io.Util;
import com.codename1.properties.*;
import com.codename1.ui.Button;
import com.codename1.ui.Container;
import com.codename1.ui.Display;
import com.codename1.ui.Form;
import com.codename1.ui.table.TableLayout;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.BorderLayout;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class Broken extends Form {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "file.db";

    public Broken() {
        super("I Am Borked", new BorderLayout());
        initDb();
        loadRecs();
    }

    private void loadRecs() {

        Button newRecordButton = new Button("Create Record");
        newRecordButton.addActionListener(e -> newRecord());
        this.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, newRecordButton);

        TableLayout layout = new TableLayout(2,10);
        Container c = new Container(layout);


        Database db = null;
        List<Prop> props = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            db = Database.openOrCreate(DATABASE_NAME);

            SQLMap sqlMap = SQLMap.create(db);
            Prop prop = new Prop();
            List<PropertyBusinessObject> objs = sqlMap.select(prop, prop.id, true, 1000, 0);


            for(PropertyBusinessObject o : objs) {
                Prop p = (Prop) o;
                Logger.log("Time RAW: " + p.time.getInt());
                props.add(p);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.log("Error: " + e.getMessage(), true);
        } finally {
            Util.cleanup(db);
        }

        for (Prop prop : props) {
            c.add(Integer.toString(prop.id.get()));
            c.add(Integer.toString(prop.time.getInt()));
        }

        this.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, c);
    }

    private void newRecord() {
        Prop prop = new Prop();
        Random random = new Random();
        prop.time.set(random.nextInt(1480 - 480 + 1) + 480);
        Logger.log("New time: " + prop.time.getInt());

        Database db = null;
        try {
            db = Display.getInstance().openOrCreate(DATABASE_NAME);
            SQLMap sqlMap = SQLMap.create(db);
            sqlMap.setPrimaryKey(prop, prop.id);
            sqlMap.insert(prop);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Log.p("Error saving list: " + ioe.getMessage());
        } finally {
            Util.cleanup(db);
        }

        this.removeAll();
        this.loadRecs();
        this.revalidate();
        //this.showBack();
    }

    private void initDb() {
        Database db = null;
        try {
            db = Display.getInstance().openOrCreate(DATABASE_NAME);
            SQLMap sqlMap = SQLMap.create(db);
            Prop prop = new Prop();
            sqlMap.setPrimaryKeyAutoIncrement(prop, prop.id);
            sqlMap.createTable(prop);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.log("Error: " + e.getMessage(), true);
        } finally {
            Util.cleanup(db);
        }
    }
}
```

And the property class:

```
package com.tvc.sisa;

import com.codename1.properties.IntProperty;
import com.codename1.properties.PropertyBusinessObject;
import com.codename1.properties.PropertyIndex;

public class Prop implements PropertyBusinessObject {


    public IntProperty<Prop> id = new IntProperty<>("id");
    public IntProperty<Prop> time = new IntProperty<>("time");
    public final PropertyIndex idx = new PropertyIndex(this, "Prop", id, time);

    public Prop() {
        id.setLabel("ID");
        time.setLabel("Time");
    }


    @Override
    public PropertyIndex getPropertyIndex() {
        return idx;
    }
}
```

Comment: cleanup might not close the Database object correctly. Can you also look at the device output in the console with DDMS or logcat and see if there is an exception thrown?

Comment: I'm not familiar with either of those tools.  They seem to be part of Android Studio.  Is there a tutorial somewhere on how to use them with Codename One?

Comment: I could only find instructions that require access to the sources from the build which I don't think free accounts allow.  If there isn't another way I won't be able to provide you with any additional debugging info.  I guess I'll try storing the time value as a String instead of Integer.

Comment: Storing as String works just fine with no other code changes.  I think that indicates a bug with IntProperty handling somewhere but I don't know how else to help isolate it at this point.

Comment: I think there is something perhaps more basic wrong.  I'm now having the same sort of issues with a different field.  A TextComponent is reporting that the bound property value is empty even though there is clearly a value typed into the field.  Is there a way to ensure that all binding events have occured so that the property is fully updated with the entries before trying to manipulate it?  That appears to be what is happening since all of this stuff works flawlessly in the simulator.

Comment: I think my issues are being caused by threading problems or not using callSerially where I'm supposed to.  I tried reading the tutorial but found it very hard to follow (too much low level detail about EDT).  Is there a "for dummies" explanation of when to use callSerially()?  Or am I way off track still?

Comment: You can open DDMS without the code. Just create a new project in Android Studio and launch the device monitor https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor.html it doesn't care if an app is running or if you have the source code. You can see if you are violating the EDT by checking the EDT violation detection flag in the simulator